# How do I get the url of an internet shortcut selected with the HTML5 input type=file in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, url, readfile

I want to get the web-address (URL/URI) of YouTub videos that a user has saved to their computer's desktop as internet shortcuts link file (*.url on a windows pc or WHAT? on a mac) and I want to be able to do this with Chrome, IE 11 or higher, Edge, or FireFox, but am having trouble with Edge.

I wrote the following code, which works fine in Chrome, IE 11, and Firefox, and can be demonstrated in this CodePen:

https://codepen.io/howardb1/pen/wxZXdY

Here is the input statement and the script code from the CodePen:

```
<!-- Get internet shortcut/link file -->

<input type="file" id="inputFile" accept=".url" />

<!-- The following script validates the selected file and
     extracts the url -->

<script>
  const inputFile      = document.getElementById( 'inputFile' );
  const outputTextarea = document.getElementById( 'outputTextarea' );
  const fileReader     = new FileReader();

  fileReader.onload = function( event ) {

    const file     = event.target.result;
    const allLines = file.split( /\r\n|\n/ );

    outputTextarea.value = inputFile.files[ 0 ].name;

    // Reading line by line

    allLines.forEach( function( line ) {

      if( line.substring( 0, 4 ) === 'URL=' ) {

        outputTextarea.value += '\n' + line.substring( 4 );

      }

    } );

  };

  fileReader.onerror = function( event ) {

    alert( event.target.error.name );

  };

  inputFile.onchange = function( event ) {

    // If the file is of the right type, then read its contents ...

    if( inputFile.files[ 0 ].name.substr( -4, 4 ) === '.url' ) {

      fileReader.readAsText( event.target.files[ 0 ] );


    }
    else {

      outputTextarea.value = 'The selected file is not an internet shortcut link file: ' + inputFile.files[ 0 ].name;

    }

  }
</script>
```

However, in Edge the select file dialog does not filter for internet shortcut, and selecting a shortcut only sometimes returns the file with the .url extension.  Instead the shortcut is followed and the web-page content is returned.

Is there a way to make Edge work like the other browsers and return the selected url file?

The second part of this question is: I don't know the file type used on a Mac for internet shortcuts, nor do I know the file structure so I can extract the actual web-address.

Would someone who knows more about Macs, please give me this information or a link to it?

Thank you.

Comment: Is this part of a bigger application? I'm curious about the use cases for this, since it seems to be alot of work just to extract a string.

Comment: Yes, I store the YouTube address in a database along with pictures, and other information in an application that creates a 'wall' that others can view, sort of like FaceBook, but actually very different.